# Bind Styles After Ajax Call

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

On mounted(), I make an ajax call which pulls in div-specific data such as position on the screen. The problem is that my custom method to set v-bind:style from the ajax data gets run before ajax is finished, thus no data is there to pull from. What is the best way to set my style after ajax is done?

Ajax call returns something like this:
[{name: 'table1', top: 10, left: 25},{name: 'table2', top: 30, left: 100}]

```js
   $(function() {
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#main',
            data: {
                tables: []
            },
            methods: {
              computeOffsets() {
                  return { top: this.tables.top + 'px', left: this.tables.left+ 'px'}
              }
            },
            mounted() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: base_url + 'tables/getTables/' + event_id
                }).done(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.tables = data;
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.table {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div class='table' v-for="table in tables" v-bind:style="computeOffsets()">
        {{table.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the table as an argument to the `computeOffsets` method.

```html
<div class="table" v-for="table in tables" :style="computeOffsets(table)">
    {{ table.name }}
</div>
```

```js
computeOffsets(table) {
    return { top: table.top + 'px', left: table.left + 'px' };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!